# Unable to commit consuming offsets to Kafka on checkpoint in Flink new Kafka consumer-api (1.14)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am referring Flink 1.14 version for the Kafka source connector with the below code.

I am expecting the below requirements.

- At the very new start of the application has to read from the latest offsets from the Kafka topic
- On checkpoint, it has to commit the consumed offsets to the Kafka
- After the restart(when the application killed manually/system error) it has to pick from the last committed offsets and should have to consume consumer lag and henceforth fresh event feeds.

With Flink new KafkaConsumer API  (KafkaSource) I am facing the below problems

- Able to do the above requirements but not able to commit the consumed offsets on a checkpoint(500ms). It rather commits after 2s or 3s.

When you kill the application manually within that 2s/3s and restart. Since the last consumed message is not committed it is read twice(duplicate).

To cross-check this feature I have tried with Flink Kafka's older consumer API (FlinkKafkaConsumer). There it is perfectly working. As and when a message is consumed immediately it is committed back to Kafka.

Steps followed

- Set up the Kafka environment
- Run the flink below code to consume. Code includes both old and new APIs. Both these APIs will consume from Kafka topic and print at the console
- Push some messages to Kafka topic.
- After pushing some messages and after they visible in console kill the Flink job.
- Check kafka consumer groups for both APIs. New flink consumer api's group-id(test1) consumer lag is > 0 compared to older consumer api's group-id(older_test1).
- When you restart Flink job, you can see those uncommitted messages are visible in the console from the new Flink kafka-consumer API leading to duplicate messages.

Please suggest if anything that I am missing or any property needs to be added.

```
 @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("FlinkKafkaStreamsTest started ..");

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(new Configuration());
        env.enableCheckpointing(500);
        env.setParallelism(4);

        Properties propertiesOld = new Properties();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        String inputTopic = "input_topic";
        String bootStrapServers = "localhost:29092";
        String groupId_older = "older_test1";
        String groupId = "test1";

        propertiesOld.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServers);
        propertiesOld.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId_older);
        propertiesOld.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServers);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);


        /******************** Old Kafka API **************/
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> flinkKafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(inputTopic,
                new KRecordDes(),
                propertiesOld);
        flinkKafkaConsumer.setStartFromGroupOffsets();
        env.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer).print("old-api");


        /******************** New Kafka API **************/
        KafkaSourceBuilder<String> sourceBuilder = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(bootStrapServers)
                .setTopics(inputTopic)
                .setGroupId(groupId)
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "false")
                .setProperty("commit.offsets.on.checkpoint", "true")
                .setProperties(properties)
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST));

        KafkaSource<String> kafkaSource = sourceBuilder.build();

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> source = env
                .fromSource(kafkaSource, WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps(), "Kafka Source");

        source.print("new-api");

        env.execute();
    }
    static class KRecordDes implements  KafkaDeserializationSchema<String>{
        @Override
        public TypeInformation<String> getProducedType() {
            return TypeInformation.of(String.class);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isEndOfStream(String nextElement) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public String deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecord) throws Exception {
            return new String(consumerRecord.value());
        }
    }
```

Note: I have other requirements where I want the Flink Kafka bounded source reader in the same code, which is available in new APIs(KafkaSource).

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of Kafka Source:

> Note that Kafka source does **NOT** rely on committed offsets for
> fault tolerance. Committing offset is only for exposing the progress
> of consumer and consuming group for monitoring.

When the Flink job recovers from failure, instead of using committed offsets on broker, it'll restore state from the latest successful checkpoint, and resume consuming from the offset stored in that checkpoint, so records after the checkpoint will be "replayed" a little bit. Since you are using print sink, which does not support exactly-once semantic, you will see duplicated records that are actually records after the latest successful checkpoint.

For the 2-3 second delay of offset commit you mentioned, it is because of the implementation of `SourceReaderBase`. In short words `SplitFetcher` manages a task queue, and when an offset commit task is pushed into the queue, it won't be executed until a running fetch task invoking `KafkaConsumer#poll()` times out. The delay could be longer if the traffic is quite small. But note that this won't affect correctness: KafkaSource doesn't use committed offset for fault tolerance.

Comment: I want to do something similar with a bounded Kafka source running in batch mode triggered every hour. So when the batch starts, it needs the offset in Kafka. I have a case where the traffic is quite small and the offset is not committed to Kafka. Are there any workarounds for  that? Since checkpoints are ignored in batch mode, I cannot rely on them.