# Flink Streaming Pipeline Not Committing Offsets to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have multiple Flink streaming applications. These applications commit offsets to Kafka every 30s or so. We're seeing that Flink is not committing offsets to Kafka at all. This leads to a mismatch in the consumer lag reported by Kafka vs Flink.

Is there a specific configuration on `KafkaSource` that we have to make so that offsets are committed no matter what?

We use this `KafkaSource` config to start the pipeline:
`.setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST))`

So, if we don't fix this consumer lag issue, Flink could potentially start consuming really old data.

I checked this post: [Unable to commit consuming offsets to Kafka on checkpoint in Flink new Kafka consumer-api (1.14)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70375310/unable-to-commit-consuming-offsets-to-kafka-on-checkpoint-in-flink-new-kafka-con) but it doesn't seem to answer what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In order for Flink to commit its offsets to Kafka, you must enable checkpointing. The Flink Kafka source commits the current consuming offset when checkpoints are completed, for ensuring the consistency between Flink’s checkpoint state and committed offsets on Kafka brokers.

Comment: The Flink docs say "If checkpointing is not enabled, Kafka source relies on Kafka consumer’s internal automatic periodic offset committing logic, configured by `enable.auto.commit` and `auto.commit.interval.ms` in the properties of Kafka consumer."

Comment: I have the checkpointing enabled, I see that my application checkpoints are successful, Kafka offset commits are not happening for some reason.